# Is there an elegant way of doing something to the last element of a for-each loop in Java?

Tags: java, programming-languages, foreach

I'm using Java 6.

Suppose I had a bunch of cats to feed, and suppose myCats is sorted.

```
for (Cat cat : myCats) {

    feedDryFood(cat);

    //if this is the last cat (my favorite), give her a tuna
    if (...) 
        alsoFeedTuna(cat);
}
```

and I wanted to treat my last cat specially.

Is there a way to do this elegantly inside the loop? The only way I can think of is counting them.

Stepping back a little bit for a wider picture, is there any programming language that supports this little feature in a for-each loop?

Comment: What is your real use of this? Can you treat the first item specially instead?

Comment: The real use, I don't know, but I'm definitely learning a lot from the nice, smart people here.

Comment: the amount of poor solutions with multiple up votes is very disturbing!

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: Then please show us the way with a better solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you need to do this, the best approach might be to use an Iterator.  Other than that, you have to count.  The iterator has a

```
hasNext()
```

method that you can use to determine if you are on the last item of your iterations.

EDIT -- To increase readability you can do something like the following within the Iterator based loop (psuedo):

```
Cat cat = iter.next();
feedDryFood(cat);

boolean shouldGetTuna = !iter.hasNext();
if (shouldGetTuna) 
    alsoFeedTuna(cat)
```

that is fairly self-documenting code via clever use of variable names.

Comment: While this certainly answers the question, the only issue I have with it is that it doesn't make the requirement "the last cat is the favorite and gets tuna" very explicit from the code. Someone reading would have to think about why the cat is given tuna if the iterator doesn't have a next item.

Comment: @colind, readability is very important.  I updated my answer on how I would make it readable and self documenting.

Answer (score 26):

@fbcocq's solution

How was this a bad solution? Just add another local variable.

```
Cat lastCat = null;

for (Cat cat : myCats) {
  feedDryFood(cat);
  lastCat = cat;
}

alsoFeedTuna(lastCat);
```

Edit: set null first to take care of cases where myCats does not set lastCat

Comment: I don't think it's a bad solution, but it doesn't follow the OP's question, where they ask if there's an elegant way to do it inside the loop.

Comment: IMHO, Its pretty elegent. Works in a few lines without special behaviour.

Comment: What happens when `myCats` is empty? Wont you get an exception?

Answer (score 9):

There's no clear way to do it within the for-each loop, but a straightforward way would be to simply use an iterator directly (the for-each hides the iterator).

Comment: @balusc: my question as well!

Comment: Someone went on a downvoting bender

Comment: yeah sometimes i get the feeling there are people out there that just want to let off some stream and go on a downvoting rampage just for fun. geek amok.

Answer (score 8):

If it's a special behavior that has to happen to the last item in the loop, then it should take place outside the loop and you should provide way to let the information escape the loop:

```
Cat lastCat = null;
for (Cat cat : cats)
{
    // do something for each cat
    lastCat = cat;
}

if (lastCat != null)
{
    // do something special to last cat
}
```

I would recommend moving the blocks of these two statements into methods.

Answer (score 5):

Use the iterator directly.

```
Cat cat
Iterator<Cat> i = myCats.iterator()
while (i.hasNext())
{
    cat = i.next()
    feedDryFood(cat);
    if (!i.hasNext())
    {
        alsoFeedTuna(cat); // Last cat.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the best thing would be to set an indicator on the cat, `isFavoured`, or maybe a static member of the `Cat` class which points to the favourite (but this way you can only have one favourite). Then just look for the indicator when you're going through the loop. After all, cats don't always eat in the same order. ;)

```
for (Cat cat : myCats) {

    feedDryFood(cat);

    if (cat.isFavoured) 
        alsoFeedTuna(cat);
}
```

Alternatively, you could convert then list to an array and then it would be easy to know when you get to the last one - but what if the last one isn't your favourite?

```
//only a rough idea, may not compile / run perfectly
catArray = cats.toArray(cats);
for (int i = 0 ; i < catArray.length(); i++){
    feedDryFood(catArray [i]);

    //check for last cat.
    if (i == catArray.length()-1 ) 
        alsoFeedTuna(catArray [i]);
}
```

---

It is not clear which is more important: for the last cat to get tuna, OR for the favourite cat to get tuna. Or... is the last cat the favourite, by definition of being last? Please clarify!

Comment: If that happens, the last one will scratch him in the face. Then, next time through the loop, you can be sure it will be his favorite.

Comment: I'm in agreement with you about the `isFavoured` property on `Cat` or something similar... this is a much stronger design than having an arbitrary position in a list indicate which cat should get tuna (unless the design actually is simply "the last cat gets tuna" for some reason). I don't agree with a static field on `Cat` for this or with converting a `List` to an array... there generally isn't any good reason to do that.

Comment: Nice idea, but won't apply when the condition is not dependent on the item itself. E.g. concatenating items to a commaseparated string. The condition then really depends on the item's position in the list.

Comment: @BalusC: Of course, joining strings with a separator is a kind of special case that's best handled by an API for that... I feel like position-dependent logic like that should be _relatively_ rare in most other situations. In this example, "favorite" seems like a designation that should decidedly not be based on position in a list.

Comment: @Frustrated: Why do you feel the need to copy the list into an array? You can access elements of a `List` by index just the same as you can an array, and using the `Iterator` is superior to index-based access since it neither involves copying to an array nor slow index-based access for a list that isn't `RandomAccess`. I'd upvote this if not for that part.

Comment: @ColinD: Because it's been a while since I've done this in Java :P

Comment: @BalusC: If you introduce strings to a problem with cats, the cats will just play with the strings and will definitely not eat in the correct order (assuming they ever did in the first place).

Comment: The last cat is always my favorite. When I tell them to line up before I feed them, I take it that the last cat is the humblest of all and deserves tuna.

Comment: @Russell: Now that's a *very* well-worded requirement (better than before, anyway). In that case I think you're best off with an Iterator or array solution because you don't care which individual gets it, as long as it's the last one.

(Also, can anyone explain the downvote?)

Comment: @Frustrated: I think some serial downvoter hit every answer on here except the first one. =/

Comment: @ColinD: Yeah that's what it looks like; I guess the sort of person who downvotes almost everything is not the sort likely to leave any explanation. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

In regards to the question of whether any programming languages support this feature, Perl's [Template Toolkit](http://tt2.org/) does:

```
[% FOR cat IN cats; feedDryFood(cat); alsoFeedTuna(cat) IF loop.last; END %]
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks! This means this feature is useful to some people after all.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it outside the loop.

The whole semantics of a foreach loop are that you do the same thing to every object. In this step though you're treating one object differently. To me it seems more sensible to do it outside of the loop.

Plus, the only ways I could think of to do it inside are horribly hacky...

Answer (score 1):

the `for...each` construct is not the proper tool to use to gain the specific behavior you are after as the question is worded, without having more features in the `Cat` object. The classic `Iterator` is designed to provide just this type of functionality. I think the question illustrates that the design is flawed, more on that latter.

Assuming that the there is a sorted list of cats called `cats`. A `List` that does not guarantee traversal order would not be a good candidate for iteration, regardless of how the list is traversed.

```
final Iterator<Cat> iterator = cats.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
   final Cat cat = iterator.next();
   this.feedDryCatFood(cat);
   // special case, if there are no more cats in the list
   // feed the last one tuna as well.
   if (!iterator.hasNext())
   {
      this.alsoFeedTuna(cat);
   }
}
```

a better solution would be to have a member method on `Cat`. `Cat.isSpecial()` that returns a `boolean`. This would be more self documenting and move the behavior out of the loop construct. Then you could use a `for...each` construct with a simple test that is self contained and self documenting.

```
if (cat.isSpecial())
{
  this.feedTuna(cat);
}
```

I think the "last element of a `for..each` loop" in the question is a red herring. I think the problem is more a design problem than a business logic problem, and the fact that the `for...each` loop can't accommodate the rule is indicative that a refactoring should occur.

This new design would also accommodate multiple "special" cats without any complication to the code.

Other more elegant Object Oriented solutions would be the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). The Visitor Pattern would abstract out the logic of who what the favorite from the `Cat` and into the Visitor implementation. Same with the Chain of Responsibility. Have a chain of `CatFeeder` objects, and let them decide whether to "handle" the feeding or pass it on down the chain. Either way would be looser coupling and tighter cohesion.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you cannot use a normal looping construct with a counter and a test for its position? It isn't like not using the foreach syntax is inelegant by default. If using the foreach construct, then I would agree using the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

> and suppose myCats is sorted

Sort it in descending order of favouritism instead of ascending order, or reverse the list before iterating

```
for (Cat cat in catsWithFavouriteFirst)
{
    cat.feed(dryFood);
    if (!tunaTin.isEmpty())
    {
        cat.feed(tunaTin.getTunaOut());
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody want to explain why they down voted a perfectly reasonable solution?

Comment: Somebody batched downvoted possibly all the threads. That sucks. Anyway, I upvoted you for the idea of re-sorting the cats.

Comment: @Russell: thanks.  I noticed there seemed to be rather a lot of down votes of a lot of reasonable answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something very simple you can do that makes it explicit that the last cat is the favorite and should get tuna is to simply get the last cat by index and give it tuna after giving all the cats dry food.

```
Cat favorite = myCats.get(myCats.size() - 1);
alsoFeedTuna(favorite);
```

This is fast and just fine if you're using a `List` that implements `RandomAccess` such as an `ArrayList`. If you're using a non-`RandomAccess` structure such as a `LinkedList`, this would be slow but you could view the list as a `Deque` instead and write:

```
Cat favorite = myCats.getLast();
```

You do of course need to ensure that `myCats` isn't empty to do this.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it was done because `myCats().size()` could possibly be zero.

Comment: @Inshallah: That's true, you would need to ensure that `myCats` isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for( Iterator<Cat> iter = cats.iterator() ; iter.hasNext(); )
    {
        Cat cat = iter.next();
        feedDryFood(cat);
        if(!iter.hasNext())
            alsoFeedTuna(cat);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using a foreach loop and putting the feedTuna method outside the loop.

```
int i = 0;
for( i = 0; i < cat.length; i++ ){
  feedDryFood(cat[i]);
}
if( cat.length != 0 ){
  feedTuna(cat[i - 1]);
}
```

This avoids any additional assignments or conditionals inside the loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
Cat cat;

for (cat : myCats) {
  feedDryFood(cat);
}

alsoFeedTuna(cat);
```

Comment: -1: doesn't compile at all :) It has really to be declared in the scope of the foreach. The `Iterator` is your most elegant bet.

Comment: My bad, foreach doesn't allow cat to be outside its scope.

Comment: There's a `delete` link below the answer.

Comment: I know, we're all learning, might as well keep it here for posterity.

Comment: In the defense of the poster: I'm pretty sure there's languages out there that actually allow this.